# Problem with fetching results with sql query in php function

Tags: php

I have php function that needs to check if the results from query are less or equal to 2, and if they are it can pass to the next step and if they are not then show error. My query works and currently it shows one result from database, so the variable that returns on the end of the function is false as it currently is. And in my code I put negation on function (with !) and then I put some error message. But it currently doesn't seem to work as it should. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

function

```
function isUniqueOrValidCC($cc) {

    $tmpret=true;
    $ccn=ccnCrypt($cc);
    $q = "select count(mid) number from billing where card='$ccn' group by mid";

    if($r_ptr=q($q)) {
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_ptr)) {
            $tmpret = $r<=2;
        }
        mysql_free_result($r_ptr);
    }
    var_dump($tmpret); die('!!!'); // WHEN I DUMP HERE I GET FALSE (IN DATABASE I HAVE ONE RECORD)
    return $tmpret;
}
```

code

```
if(!isUniqueOrValidCC($qdata['ccn']) {

    echo "ERROR! This credit card is already in use on an existing account"
}
```

I know it is not the best code out there and I will change that in the future, but currently I need help with this situation.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: @Dharman Yeah I know that, but in my situation I need it to be like this. I will change it in the future.

Comment: PHP 5 hasn't been supported for many years. Please change it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Dharman Yeah I know that too :) But can you help me in this situation?

Comment: When you execute `isUniqueOrValidCC($qdata['ccn'])` what is the output? I ignore the syntax error and the `die()` assuming you just made a mistake when copying it here.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($r)` inside the loop and check what you're actually comparing against. Considering that you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, it should be an array. So `$r <= 2` will check if the array is less or equal to the integer `2` (which  will evaluate as `false` since it's like comparing apples and oranges)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I get this when I dump $r inside the while   array(1) { 'used_number' => string(1) "1" }

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` actually returns an array, something like this: `$r['number']`, I think you expect a number?

Comment: @Dharman - I know?

Comment: Ok, I see. You didn't want to compare against an array. You want a single result from the query. Then you need to remove the whole `while` and just use `mysql_fetch_assoc($r_ptr)['number']` assuming that your PHP version supports it.

Comment: try to open code in some IDE (phpstorm for example) and you will see some errors in your code

Comment: @KIKOSoftware So I put $r['number]<=2 and now in dump bellow it changed to true.

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't intend on comparing an array to a number. What you want is to fetch the value from your result set. Since you only expect a single value there is no need for a `while` loop.

```
function isUniqueOrValidCC($cc) {
    $ccn = ccnCrypt($cc);
    $q = "select count(mid) number from billing where card='$ccn' group by mid";

    if($r_ptr = q($q)) {
        $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_ptr);
        return $r && $r['number'] <=2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Please consider upgrading to a supported PHP version. It is irresponsible to run such an old version.**